# FileVault and TimeMachine restoration - Unable to turn on FileVault again

Tags: time-machine, filevault, network

I have restored a MBP timemachine backup to a new MBP. On my older machine I have enabled FileVault.

The restoration was long. It took about almost 12 hours to transfer 500Gb of data.

In the new unit I have experienced a few problem (e.g. unable to install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) )

When I checked FileValut setting in 'Security & Privacy', I can see it is turned off.

[image]

When I tried to turn it on, I got this dialog box

[image]

and then this dialog box appears:

[image]

A 'Meraki Management' profile is installed on this MBP.

Answer (score 1):

After some investigation, the problem has something to do with [`nix`](https://nixos.org/nix/manual/), which I have installed on my old MBP.

To make FileVault work again, I have to remove all the `nix` users and `nix` user group.